# New car - Front Left suspension "clicking"

Tags: nissan, suspension, shock-absorber, swaybar

I recently bought a new car and noticed when I go over speed bumps (either directly or at an angle), the front left suspension "clicks", and I feel that click through my steering wheel.

Im not sure how to better convey the feeling, but if someone can provide possible causes for this it would be much appreciated.

Once again, I'm concerned because the car has only 100 miles on it so far.

Cheers!

Comment: It could be just a quirk of the model you have, or it could be a sign of something serious, there's really no way to say. As it's brand new and under warranty you should take it straight back to the dealer.

Comment: That doesn't sound normal.  I recall some years ago I bought a new car and it made a clicking sound when the steering wheel was turned.  The dealer swore this was normal but none of the other same model cars on the lot did it.  Finally the factory rep looked at it and said the steering gear was defective.  They replaced it (under warranty) and the problem was solved.  Since this is a new vehicle and I assume it has a warranty, don't take "it's normal" for an answer!

Comment: Cheers guys, will take it back to the dealer and have it checked!